# Detect control + RightKey in RichtextBox in Visual Webgui

Tags: visual-web-gui

Please, how do i detect control + rightkey in ricktextbox in visualwebgui ?

Event keyDown, keyPress and keyUp not working.

Thanks

I'm trying to use the events but they don't work

private void ggggg_KeyDown(object objSender, KeyEventArgs objArgs)
{

```
    }
```